# How to I do a sum with multiple conditions with groupby in python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
## filter group by 
df.groupby('Season')['Cost'].sum()['Winter']
```

I am able to do with singular condition where Season = Winter.
How do I do it with multiple conditions? Please view the SQL equivalent that I am trying to achieve on Python.

```
Select 
Season
,sum(cost) 
from df 
where Season in ('Winter','Summer')
group by Season
and 
Select 
Season
,sum(cost) 
from df 
where Season in ('Winter','Summer')
and Region ='Europe'
group by Season
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data first then do groupby

```
filter_df = df[(df.Season.isin(['Winter','Summer'])) & (df.Region =='Europe')]
filter_df.groupby('Season')['Cost'].sum()
```